# WPF AutoCompleteBox Multiple ValueMemberPath

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, ivalueconverter, autocompletebox

I have a CollectionViewSource populated with business objects from a database. Setting
the AutoCompleteBox ValueMemberPath="LNAME" works as intended for all last names. However, I would like to search first name and order number concurrently without having to resort to radio buttons or a dropdown to define search type.

I have changed ValueMemberPath to ValueMemberBinding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TheCollectionViewSource}}"
ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValueMemberPathConverter}}"
```

I am not sure how to combine the LNAME, FNAME etc in the converter

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return foo;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return foo;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public Binding ValueMemberBinding
    {
      get
      {
        return _valueBindingEvaluator != null ?
          _valueBindingEvaluator.ValueBinding : null;
      }
      set
      {
        if (_valueBindingEvaluator == null)
        {
          _valueBindingEvaluator = new BindingEvaluator<string>();
          AddLogicalChild(_valueBindingEvaluator);
        }
        _valueBindingEvaluator.ValueBinding = value;
      }
    }
```